# RCP Product: add @start to a bundle in config.ini file

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have a plugin which I need to start explicitly by adding @start to the /configuration/config.ini file.

The plug-in only starts if I replace the ending '@4:start' to '@start' with Notepad or any editor.

How can I achieve that from the .product file? (So that I don't have to replace the ending each time I export the product)

FURTHER INFO:

I tried setting Start Levels to @1, @2 etc. But the program terminates at splash-screen.

Also, I did go around the editor and replaced Start Level's value with 'start' in the product file. But then the export stops saying it's corrupt.

Before switching to the E4 platform the plugin started by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your product file inside `<product></product>` tag:

```
<configurations>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" autoStart="true" startLevel="4" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      .....      
</configurations>
```

Comment: I clicked on Add Recommended button. It did add these and also some others too. Then I added my plugin with starLevel=2 and now it works, Thank you!